# Attach a char limit to each comment area jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I am having some issues, and cannot solve this, since I cannot get my head around this. It's kinda a big issue. I want to dynamically attach a char limit and a submit comment button to each post, and each commentArea to be a form of its own. Any help is welcome, I want to **make it dynamic, independent from each other**.

Thanks!

```
   $(".comment-box").keyup(function(){
        var text_max = 140;
        var length_reached = $(this).val().length;
        var remaining = text_max - length_reached;
        $('.counter').html(remaining);

        if(remaining < 5 || remaining > text_max)
           $(".btn").prop("disabled", true);
        else
           $(".btn").prop("disabled", false);
    });
```

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3sCfG/25/

**EDIT: Trying to make something similar to Twitter's Reply section which is attached to each micropost on their Timeline, but not sure if IDs should be used, found IDs on Twitter's, but not fully clear. I am trying to make a similar comment box to that of Twitter's.**

Comment: what's the actual issue you're having?   You haven't said in the question text.

Comment: @Alnitak        Trying to make something similar to Twitter's Reply section which is attached to each micropost on their Timeline, but not sure if IDs should be used, found IDs on Twitter's, but not fully clear. I am trying to make a similar comment box to that of Twitter's.

Comment: no, that's a "requirement", not a "problem"

Comment: Here's Twitter's:   <textarea name="status" class="tweet-box-shadow" id="tweet-box-reply-to-334934164774191107"></textarea>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/3sCfG/38/

**CODE**

```
$(".comment-box").keyup(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var text_max = 140;
    var length_reached = $(this).val().length;
    var remaining = text_max - length_reached;

    $(parent).find('.counter').html(remaining);

    if (remaining < 5 || remaining >= text_max)
        $(parent).find(".btn").prop("disabled", true);
    else
        $(parent).find(".btn").prop("disabled", false);
    });
```

hope it helps

---

**EDIT** cleaned up code a little

Comment: Thanks, almost there. Should I be using IDs or not, in addition, how can I add so that it disables the button again, when going back to 140 chars?

Comment: @JohnSmith updated code and fiddle with your last request. anyway, id's are surely helpfull to target directly your elements, but with class you can better handle multiple elements at one time.

Comment: should I be using IDs, I will have this under forms so that users can submit, but the question is whether IDs are to be used or NOT, I checked Twitter's website, and I found an ID, but still unsure, can you guide me, what do you think? As you might have noticed by know, this is to function like Twitter's reply section on each post.

Comment: for what you are doing, I don't see the need to add an ID. Anyway, add it anyway. It could be helpful in the future.

Comment: @BeNdErR IMHO there's way too much repetition in this code.  You should also never use a `[class='counter']` attribute selector which requires an _exact_ match (excluding all other classes) when you could just use `.counter`.

Comment: @BeNdErR       How can you be so sure? I am having this under a <form>

Comment: @JohnSmith I rely on the code I see and you provided at the time the question was posted.. @ Alnitak yup, it could be cleaned up a bit

Comment: @BeNdErR        Your clean up of the code made the disable/enable button to run into another issue.

Comment: @BeNdErR          "@JohnSmith I rely on the code I see and you provided at the time the question was posted.", yes, I know. But still, to do this professionally and correctly, shouldn't IDs be used to make more separation and create a isolation from other elements on the DOM?

Comment: @JohnSmith the question of use of IDs is completely separate to what you've _actually asked_ in the original question which related to broken DOM traversal code.  That said, there's no "right answer" to that.   If you need to access a _single_ element by some identifier, you likely need an ID.  But you might not.  "It depends".

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is using classes (hence affecting multiple elements) without specifying which part of the DOM you're trying to update.

The simplest solution is to add a  "search context" to the selectors in your handler.

I've used `$(selector, parent)` as a shorthand for `$(parent).find(selector)`:

```
$(".comment-box").keyup(function() {

    var parent = this.parentNode;  // new
    var text_max = 140;
    var length_reached = this.value.length;
    var remaining = text_max - length_reached;

    $('.counter', parent).html(remaining);
    $('.btn', parent).prop('disabled', (remaining < 5 || remaining >= text_max));
});
```

I've also refactored the `.prop` call, since:

```
if (condition) {
    .prop('disabled', true);
} else {
    .prop('disabled', false);
}
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
.prop('disabled', condition);
```

and I changed the `> text_max` to `>= text_max`, since I presume the intent was to disable the "submit" button if there's no input.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/ATW9u/

Comment: Your code example does not solve the issue for <form> and disable/enable submit button.

Comment: @JohnSmith the fiddle appears to work for me.  What are you seeing?

Comment: Go back to 140 chars hitting backspace, and you'll see that the button remains Enabled.

Comment: ah - the link is to the wrong version of the fiddle.  The code here is correct.  I've updated the fiddle link now.

Comment: Ah! I see, well that explains a alot.

Comment: yeah, I just forgot to press the "set as base" button on jsfiddle

Comment: It's OK I guess, do not have much logic to add.

Answer (score 0):

- Maybe add a `data-` attribute to text area and use that to set the max length?

  ```
  <textarea class="comment-box" type="text" data-limit="10" placeholder="Write a comment"><textarea>
  ```
- along with that, instead of referring to the counter with its class, navigate to it and reduce the no. of characters from it. (Like this)

  ```
  $(this).next(".tools").find("span").html(remaining);
  ```

Gives the `textareas` the inpedendance you wanted to give them. Heres your updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3sCfG/28/

Comment: In HTML5, textareas have a native `.maxlength` property - why not use that?

Comment: @JohnSmith NO BAD MOUTHING :O

Comment: @JohnSmith I was suggesting that you could just use `maxlength="140"` in the HTML instead of `data-limit="10"` and then you get the best of both worlds - on HTML5 browsers it'll enforce the limit, and on any browser version you can access `$(this).attr('maxlength')` to find the supplied value.

Comment: @passionateCoder    Fine, I am sorry dude! :P

Comment: @Alnitak        Thanks, I will do a quick test!

Comment: @JohnSmith you should also carefully study my actual answer and then see how dumb you think I am.

Comment: @Alnitak,      I am sorry for what I wrote, but I really want to keep supporting the old browsers for now, as the majority of users still use old software, even Windows XP and Windows 98, 95.

Comment: @JohnSmith if you read my previous comment you'll see how using `maxlength` can support _all_ browsers, but provide an automatically _enhanced_ experience for new browsers.

Comment: @Alnitak, I do NOT see any MaxLength attribute on Twitter: <textarea name="status" class="tweet-box-shadow" id="tweet-box-reply-to-334934164774191107"></textarea>

Comment: Twitter isn't exactly a good role model (`<i>` tag for icons, really?).  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea